# DISABLE automatic store listing translation in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, translation

How can I disable the automatic translation of my app description? I seriously don't want to translate my app in > 70 languages...
My customers are fine with English only.

Comment: Agreed, such a ridiculous Google Play feature. They definitely should give app developers the option to disable auto translations altogether for an app. I want to provide quality (manual) translations for *supported* languages (typically the same ones the app itself is localised into), and *English* for the rest, not a lousy machine translation.

Answer (score 3):

I asked Google the same question. They say it is up to end users -- not the developer -- to select whether Play Store listings are automatically translated. So I guess to answer your question: you can't.

They advise obtaining accurate translations and setting up language-specific store fronts instead.

Comment: please link some source

Comment: @kwarunek The source is (private) communication with Google Play Developer Support.

Comment: How can users disable automatic translation?