# Android google play : disable automatically translation of short description

Tags: android, google-play, google-translate

I have pubblished an app on Android Play store and I selected english US language and I have put an english short and long description.

With an italian smartphone I opened my app page on Google play store, but the short description was automatically translated in italian. Why ? I don't want the translation. Is possible ? where I wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DISABLE automatic store listing translation in Google Play](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881619/disable-automatic-store-listing-translation-in-google-play)

Answer (score 1):

This might be too simple: you could provide your own "Italian" - which could actually be an exact copy of the English.