# Prevent Google play from auto translating my app description

Tags: android, google-play, translation

I have an app on google play with its description in English. However, our clients in Finland see the app description in very bad Finnish translation of the description. Is there an option while submitting my app to stop the auto translation and only use English? I have come across some undecisive answers on SO.

Also, when I open the store listing of my app in Google play developer console, I see an option to "Manage translations" where I can add my description in whatever language I want to. I want to know how this works and is suggested.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @downvoter Any specific reason to downvote the post?

Comment: Not the downvoter but given that a quick search on `google play publisher description language` shows me this page: 
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3125566?hl=en and there is a section `Add translations for Store Listing pages` which provides instructions.

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks for the reply. As mentioned in the question I have already done your suggestion, I just want to know how it works ie. will the devices set to that particular language be able to see the description in thaat language and others in English?

Comment: From the page I linked to: `After you publish an app on Google Play, automated translations of your app's Store Listing page are available to Google Play users.` So if you don't provide a specific language translation, Google gives the choice to the user of seeing a automatic translation.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks for the explanation. Please submit as an answer for me to accept

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DISABLE automatic store listing translation in Google Play](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881619/disable-automatic-store-listing-translation-in-google-play)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From this link:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3125566?hl=en

There is a section `Add translations for Store Listing pages` which covers your question.

The specific quote on how Google Play treats translations of Store Listings:

> After you publish an app on Google Play, automated translations of your app's Store Listing page are available to Google Play users.
>
> If users visit your app's Store Listing on Google Play in a language that you haven't translated, they can choose to view an automated translation of your app's page. Near the top of the page, there will be a notification that explains the translation has been done automatically, along with an option to view the Store Listing in its default language instead.

So if you don't provide a specific language translation, Google gives the choice to the user of seeing a automatic translation.

Comment: In my experience, the user does not get to op in or out of the automated translation, and it is not made clear at all that the description has been translated automatically.

Comment: There definitely should be an option *for the app developer* to disable auto translations altogether.

Comment: is the automatic translation enabled by default or not?